# Как отформатировать поле DateTimeField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, django-admin

В models.py есть поле с типом DateTimeField, как отформатировать его? Например сделать так чтобы в django-admin по умолчанию выводилось не 06.03.2019, а 2019.06.03.?

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='Дата и время',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форматирование определяется там, где отображается дата: в форме или django-admin.

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('new_format_date',)

    def new_format_date(self, obj):
        return obj.date.strftime('%Y.%b.%d')

    new_format_date.short_description = 'Отформатированная дата'
```

Comment: куда мне добавить этотт участок кода?

Comment: @НеуловимыйДжо в `admin.py`